# Parsing only dates in a list of string

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

Is it possible to check and parse **only** dates from this list :

```
List<string> everything = new List<string>
                   {"1", "A", "11/05/2013 22:43", "2.3", "21/11","null", "2012"};
```

This should return only parsed value of `11/05/2013 22:43`.
Values `2.3` and `21/11` should not be returned.

Comment: Sure... can you define what dates are? Is 21/11 a date?

Comment: "21/11" and "2.3" are not DateTime

Comment: Please see my post,  2.3  can be converted into date without an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTimke.TryParse`. You can use  following LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = everything
    .Select(str => str.TryGetDate(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Where(d => d.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value);
```

`TryGetDate` is following extension which is handy for LINQ queries:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDate(this string item, params IFormatProvider[] formatProvider)
{
    if (formatProvider.Length == 0)
        formatProvider = new[]{ CultureInfo.CurrentCulture };
    bool success = false;
    DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (var provider in formatProvider)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParse(item, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
        if (success) break;
    }
    return success ? (DateTime?)d : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

Result:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dates)); // 11/05/2013, 02/03/2013
```

**Edit**: since you want to parse *exact* use `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Here is another method that returns your desired result:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDateExact(this string item, String[] allowedFormats = null, params IFormatProvider[] formatProvider)
{
    if (formatProvider.Length == 0)
        formatProvider = new[] { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture };
    if (allowedFormats == null || allowedFormats.Length == 0)
    {
        allowedFormats = formatProvider
        .Select(fp => { 
            DateTimeFormatInfo dti = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(fp); 
            return String.Format("{0} {1}", dti.ShortDatePattern, dti.ShortTimePattern);
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
    bool success = false;
    DateTime d = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (var provider in formatProvider)
    {
        success = DateTime.TryParseExact(item, allowedFormats, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
        if (success) break;
    }
    return success ? (DateTime?)d : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

You can use it in this way:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = everything
    .Select(str => str.TryGetDateExact(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .Where(d => d.HasValue)
    .Select(d => d.Value);
```

Note that i've used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to force `/` as separator. You can omit all parameters if you want to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` only with your format string.

Comment: Tim, data is really polluted, and this should **only** return "11/05/2013 22:43".

Comment: @hdoghmen: I've edited my answer. Now it returns only `11/05/2013 22:43`.

Comment: what if it contains "02.03.2013" and this is also a valid date

Comment: Should be `new[]{"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}`

Comment: @hdoghmen: Note that i've edited the `TryGetDateExact` extension to handle the case that no format is specified. Now it is derived from the provided `IFormatProvider`(s).

Comment: @Magnus: was your last comment addressed to me?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yes just a small note for when you call `TryGetDateExact`

Comment: @Magnus: But i've already posted that format in _"You can use it in this way..."_. Now it even uses this format if you don't provide an format explicitly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Its just that it wont compile since it is not an array.

Comment: @Magnus: Whoops. I've forgotten that it wasn't a `params` array since only one is allowed. Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime.TryParse`: just try parsing every string in the list, and if parsing succeeded it's a DateTime

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

```
List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();

foreach (String st in everything) {
  DateTime dateTime;

  if (DateTime.TryParse(st, out dateTime)) // <- Probably you'll want to specify datetime formats here
    datas.Add(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: NOTE the value "2.3" will also be included which is not in proper date format

Comment: That's why I've put a comment "Probably, you'll want to specify datetime format here..."

Comment: Yes you're right and agreed, but if a date time format is included then the other valid date format other than specified will also be discarded.

Comment: @Jade but `2.3` _is_ a "valid" date format. That is why you would want to specify the formats.

Comment: @Magnus, is this also a valid date 02.03.2013 or 02-03-2013 or 02/03/2013. what if all those format is included in the list?

Answer (score 0):

**This will ignore "2.3" as valid date value**

```
        List<string> everything = new List<string> { "20131105", "1", "A", "11/05/2013 22:43", "2.3", "21/11", "null", "2012" };
        List<string> allDates = new List<string>();
        DateTime d;
        foreach (string s in everything)
        {
            if (s.Length < 8) continue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(s, out d))
            {
                allDates.Add(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works too, i'm afraid the `s.Length < 10` may skip correct data to be parsed in my big list

Comment: Yes i have have change it to 8, and might some checking need to be done but you have the starting point atleast.